# Create dynamic input type with JS

Tags: javascript

Can some tell why this is not working?

My objective is to create a list input type and assign each of them a class

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id','Maincontainer');
document.body.append(container);


var count = ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'];
var i;
for( i = 0; i <= count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML += '<input>';
}


count.forEach( function(){
    count = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    count.setAttribute('class',i);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply one class from the list to each of the possible input fields?  So input field 1 would get class1, input field 2 would get class2, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign `class` from `count` array to each input element right?

Then in the callback for `forEach` you need to provide the `element` and the `index` for class name and the corresponding input element respectively.

Moreover, `document.getElementsByTagName` is an array so you need to know which input element you want to modify by the index and check out the `forEach` semantics https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

You are passing an `i` which was used from the last for loop, it's value is always going to be the value where the first loop left which is equal to the number of input elements minus 1.

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

count.forEach(function(className, index){
    count = inputElements[index];
    count.setAttribute('class',className);
});
```

```js
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id','Maincontainer');
document.body.append(container);


var count = ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'];
var i;
for( i = 0; i <= count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML += '<input>';
}

var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

count.forEach( function(className, index){
    count = inputElements[index];
    count.setAttribute('class',className);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id','Maincontainer');
document.body.append(container);


var count = ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'];
var i;
for( i = 0; i <= count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML += '<input type="button">';
}


count.forEach( function(c, i){
    count1 = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i];
    count1.setAttribute('class',c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that next code is good way:

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id','Maincontainer');
let input = document.createElement('input');
let count = ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'];

for(let i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
  let cloneInput = input.cloneNode();
  cloneInput.classList.add(count[i]);
  container.appendChild(cloneInput);  
}

document.body.append(container);
```

This code is faster ,because conainer insert to document with all childNode, and DOM  is redrawn once.  If use createElement instead of innerHtml, native code create new element without serrialize html, so faster. And I do not use many times find elemet in DOM.  You can try foreach  instead of loop for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the newly-created input elements into a variable.

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Then, in the `forEach` function, create a new variable for the current input element you're on, and set its class to the className stored in your original `count` array.

```
count.forEach(function (className, index) {
    var currentInputElement = inputElements[index];
    currentInputElement.setAttribute('class', className);
});
```

Hope this helps!